# Changing the letters of a string

Tags: python

I have to write a code that shifts each letter of a string (cipher) a given number (shift) further through the alphabet.  The code I've written so far is as follows (with an example to test the function):

```
    def decode(cipher, shift):
        letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        for letter in cipher:
            index = letters.index(letter)
            cipher = cipher.replace(letter, letters[index-shift])
        return cipher
    print decode("LIPPSASVPH", 4)
```

It almost works, except what is happening is that as the code runs through cipher, it will change any letter that matches the one it is currently changing, so for my example, it's supposed to return "HELLOWORLD" but it instead returns "DELLOWORLD" because the last letter of cipher is H, and the code previously changed the L at the beginning of cipher to an H, so then the code changes both H's to D's.  Any suggestions on how to make the code run on each letter individually without changing other letters as well?  Thanks so much, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a new variable to store the result and return it

```
def decode(cipher, shift):
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    result = ''
    for letter in cipher:
        index = letters.index(letter)
        result += letters[index - shift]
        # cipher = cipher.replace(letter, letters[index - shift])
    return result
print decode("LIPPSASVPH", 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I had tried something similar with creating an empty string only I left the code you commented out and put the result += after that, and obviously that doesn't make sense for the way the code would run through!  Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new variable to hold the result instead of changing cipher in place. Something like this will do the trick:

```
def decode(cipher, shift):
  result = ""
  letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  for letter in cipher:
      index = letters.index(letter)
      #cipher = cipher.replace(letter, letters[index-shift])
      result += letters[index-shift]
return result
print (decode("LIPPSASVPH", 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing every `L`, `D`, etc. in the string when you use `str.replace`. You could try something like this:

```
def decode(cipher, shift):
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    new_cipher = []
    for letter in cipher:
        new_cipher.append(letters[letters.index(letter)-shift])
    return ''.join(new_cipher)
```

You basically find the corresponding code-letter and append it to a list. At the end, you turn the ordered list elements into a string using `''.join()`.

Result:

```
>>> decode("LIPPSASVPH", 4)
'HELLOWORLD'
```

Edit: Here's a one-liner (well, the new-cipher creation is):

```
>>> letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> cipher = 'LIPPSASVPH'
>>> shift = 4
>>> new_cipher = ''.join(letters[letters.index(letter)-shift] for letter in cipher)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be modifying strings just fine.  An alternative is to convert the string to a list and modify the elements that way.  It may help you dumb-down your function a bit more to simplify debugging.

```
x = "Hello"
y = list(x)
# y is now ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
y[1] = 'i'
# y is now ['H', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'o']
x = str(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the result in a new variable as others have suggested, but my instinct would be to take a completely different approach. I would make a mapping of ciphertext to plaintext with [`maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans), and then use [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) to decipher:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>>
>>> def decode(cipher, shift):
...     letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
...     shift = shift % len(letters)
...     mapping = maketrans(letters[shift:] + letters[:shift], letters)
...     return cipher.translate(mapping)
...
>>> print decode("LIPPSASVPH", 4)
HELLOWORLD
```